# Custom message - Transaction Security policy

Tags: transaction-security-policy

In Transaction Security policy, this is a standard out of box message. Is there a way to write our custom message? End user may not be in a position to understand what this message is.

Access Blocked

The operation you requested isn't allowed due to a security policy in your organization. Contact your administrator for more information about security policies.

Comment: I found no way to do this -- since this is a security violation, best practice might be to not disclose any tips as to how to get around the violation and that could explain the SFDC implementation

Comment: Thank you @cropredy for the information.